# Weechat Ruby Plugin - Trying to require any gem results in an error

Tags: ruby, rubygems, irc, mysql2

I'm trying to create a plugin that uses mysql2 which will allow communication to a database from IRC.

The problem I am facing is that I can not require any gems into the plugin without it crashing.

```
require 'mysql2'
@client = nil
def weechat_init
  Weechat.register('sql', 'Ninjex', '1.0', 'GPL3', 'Execute MySQL commands: /sql <query>', '', '')
  Weechat.hook_command('sql', 'Execute MySQL database commands', '', '', '', 'sql', '')
  return Weechat::WEECHAT_RC_OK
end

def sql(data, buffer, args)
  buffer = Weechat.current_buffer
  con_flag = '-c'
  explode = args.split(' ')
  if explode[0] == con_flag
    #Weechat.buffer_set(buffer, 'localvar_set_con', explode.drop(1).join.strip)
    con_info = explode.drop(1) # ["localhost", "username", "password", "database"]
    hostname = con_info[0]
    username = con_info[1]
    password = con_info[2]
    database = con_info[3]
    @client = Mysql2::Client.new(:host => hostname, :username => username, :password => password, :database => database)
    Weechat.print(buffer, "MySQL client created!")
  else
    row_count = 0
    Weechat.command(buffer, "Sending query: #{args}")
    sql_res = @client.query(args)
    sql_res.each(:as => :array) {|r| row_count += 1; Weechat.command(buffer, "RESULT [#{row_count.to_s}]: "+r.to_s)}
    return Weechat::WEECHAT_RC_OK
  end
end
```

The error message:

```
09:27:38 =!= | ruby: error while loading file "/home/ninjex/.weechat/ruby/sql.rb"
09:27:38 =!= | ruby: error: (eval):31:in `module_eval': cannot load such file -- mysql2 (LoadError)
09:27:38 =!= | ruby: error:      from /usr/lib/ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/custom_require.rb:36:in    `require'
```

One thing I note is:

`ninjex@kali:~$ ruby -v
ruby 2.1.1p76 (2014-02-24 revision 45161) [i686-linux]`

I am using ruby 2.1.1, and the error output shows it looking for the gem in: `/usr/lib/ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/`

Loading `mysql2` in an interactive Ruby session or inside a regular Ruby script works with success. It's only when trying to apply this with weechat that I receive the error.

Any help would be appreciated, if it is the gem path, I'm not aware of how to change the path of the gems being loaded.

Answer (score 0):

I figured this out. Weechat at it's current version is not supporting Ruby >= 2.1.x

The fix, unfortunately is running Weechat witch Ruby <= 1.9.3